# Resize PV on LVM

Tags: lvm

I have this:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        1217     9775552   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            1218       60801   478608480   83  Linux
```

And I'd like to shrink `sda2` by about 10 Gigs to give some more space to `sda1`. `sda2` is a PV on an LVM, but there is some free space in the VG so I don't have to worry about filesystem shrinking.

How can I tell my LVM to move the data off of the first 10 gigs of `sda2` and then redo my partition table to give it to `sda1`?

(I don't have enough free space to just `pvremove sda2`, which would be the easy solution).

Comment: If there is free space in your volume group, why don't you simply create a new volume and move some files over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man pvresize.

But once you've done that, you'll have a somewhat bigger problem of shrinking sda2 and then relocating all of it to the end of your disk, since the reclaimed space will be at the end of the disk, and you need to get that space between right after the end of sda1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use gparted/parted to move the partition/pv up.

Comment: This is only true from the Oct 2012 release of Gparted 0.14.0 stable - earlier releases don't support moving PVs (LVM physical volumes): http://gparted.sourceforge.net/news.php?item=151 - the LVM code is new and apparently good quality, but backups are recommended of course as there is little experience with this feature yet.